# SVG not changing size

Tags: html, css, svg

I have created an `svg heart` with a background image inside.

I'm trying to make the svg larger, but changing the width and height on both the pattern and the svg itself does not work.

```html
    <svg
    
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1" height="315" width="345" >
    
     <!-- START SVG RULES -->
    <defs>
    <!-- DEFINE IMAGE INSIDE PATTERN -->
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325185/pexels-photo-325185.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" /></pattern>
    
    <!-- SVG SHAPE CREATION -->
    <g id="heart">
    <path
    d="M0 200 v-200 h200
    
        a100,100 90 0,1 0,200
    
        a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0
    
        z" />
    </g>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#heart" class="outline" fill="url(#img1)"  />
    </svg>
```

Comment: Define a `viewbox` on the SVG....not a height and width

Comment: add border to svg and you will see that height/width are working

Answer (score 0):

For a resizable SVG use `viewBox="0 0 315 345"`instead `height="315" width="345"`

```html
    <svg
    
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 315 345" >
    
     <!-- START SVG RULES -->
    <defs>
    <!-- DEFINE IMAGE INSIDE PATTERN -->
    <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
    <image xlink:href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/325185/pexels-photo-325185.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=750&w=1260" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" /></pattern>
    
    <!-- SVG SHAPE CREATION -->
    <g id="heart">
    <path
    d="M0 200 v-200 h200
    
        a100,100 90 0,1 0,200
    
        a100,100 90 0,1 -200,0
    
        z" />
    </g>
    </defs>
    <use xlink:href="#heart" class="outline" fill="url(#img1)"  />
    </svg>
```

Answer (score -3):

Click the resize button to see if this is what you need.

https://jsfiddle.net/gbxquc05/29/

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 400 400">
```

Drawing paths in SVG is unfortunately limitted to absolute units. This is a workaround using viewBox to create coordinate system that transforms to percentage.